# Difference between creating a new table vs keeping a field in psql

Tags: postgresql, database-design, foreign-keys, relationship

What is the difference between creating a new table rather than just keeping a field. For instance...

table `Book` has the following fields

- `title:String`
- `summary:String`
- `ISBN:String`
- `language:Language`

table `Language` has the following fields

- `name:String`

instead of doing `language:Language` couldn't we just do `language:String`. I know we can do this and that it will work but my question is what are the benefits to creating a new table Language and having a `Foreign Key` in table `Book`.

Answer (score 0):

First, the correct term is “column”, not “field”.

The advantages of a lookup table are:

- you can save space, if the string is longer than a few characters
- you automatically prevent people from inserting values other than those in the lookup table, thus improving data quality

Comment: Thanks for the correction. Also, can you explain further what you mean by preventing people from inserting values other than those in the lookup table. There are no languages created at all. This content is dynamic I believe and can be added by a user with authorization. I'm getting this from the tutorial found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/Models) You can `ctrl-f` for `language` and the 6th occurrence of it is where you can find the paragraph of this. A model is represented as well on this page.

Comment: If `language` is a string, you could `INSERT` values like `English`, `english`, `ENGLISH` or `EN`. Sure, you can prevent that with a check constraint, but then you need an `ALTER TABLE` whenever you add or remove a language.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not quite understanding. With a different table I can do this as well. I can add `English`, `EN`, and `english` and so on and it all shows up as different options. These values are still inserted.

Comment: Yes, but that requires that you have permission to insert in the lookup table. And even if you do, the application user interface may not allow you to add anything to that lookup table, and you have to specify the language from a drop-down generated from the lookup table.